# Second-order optical conductivity in Green's function form

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electric-current, electrical-resistance, non-linear-optics

In linear response, Kubo formula can be given in terms of eigenstates and the Hamiltonian as
$$\sigma_{\mu\nu}(\omega)=\frac{i\hbar}{V}\sum_{mn} \frac{f_n-f_m}{\varepsilon_m-\varepsilon_n} \frac{\langle n \lvert v_{\mu}\rvert m\rangle  \langle m \lvert v_{\nu}\rvert n\rangle}{\hbar(\omega +i\eta)+\varepsilon_n-\varepsilon_m}.\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
It can also be written in terms of electron Green's functions as ($\pi$ is the polarization closely related to $\sigma$) $$\pi_{ab}(\omega)=\frac{ie^2}{\beta}\sum_{\textbf{k},\omega_n}\mathrm{tr}\left[v_a(\textbf{k}) G_0(\textbf{k},\omega_n)v_b(\textbf{k}) G_0(\textbf{k},\omega_n+\nu_m)\right]\bigg\rvert_{\nu_m\rightarrow\omega+i0^+}\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
where $\bf{v}=\partial_\textbf{k}h_\textbf{k}$ is the velocity operator of the Hamiltonian $h_\textbf{k}$ and $G_0$ is the (single-particle) Green's function.

Considering **second-order** optical responses, e.g., second-harmonic current, there are [studies](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.61.5337) giving conductivity formulas in terms of eigenstates and the Hamiltonian, i.e., similar to \eqref{eq1}.
But is there any formalism or result similar to \eqref{eq2}, i.e., written in terms of electron Green's functions, for the second-order optical response?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really get what kind of result you are looking for. Can you maybe provide other details?

Comment: @Matteo Updated. Let me know if anything unclear.

Comment: Ok! But isn't (2) a result already? If you want to go further, you need to know the explicit expression of the Green function, so for non interacting electrons on a lattice with dispersion $\varepsilon_k$ you get $1/(i\omega_n-\varepsilon_k)$ and now you should do the sum. But the result really depends on the specific system

Comment: @Matteo I want the second-order version of (2).

Comment: I am no expert on optical conductivities, but maybe this article is useful: https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.04924 . Rewriting the expressions in terms of lesser/greater green functions instead of the reduced density matrix should be straight-forward.